# Display lesser number of page links?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

How can i limit pagination
There are lot of records i want to show limited pagination
Is there any problem in view code or helper class code
Paging show like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,9,10,11,12]
***Mvc5 Paging Helper Class***

```
public static class PagingHelpers
{

         public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                          PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                          Func<int, string> pageUrl)
    {

        int pageSize = 3;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        TagBuilder tag;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            tag = new TagBuilder("a");

            tag.MergeAttribute("href",pageUrl(i));


            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
            if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
            {
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
            }
            if (i >= pagingInfo.CurrentPage - pageSize && i <= pagingInfo.CurrentPage +    pageSize)
            {



            }
            tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
            result.Append(tag.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }

}
```

***Retrieving in View***

```
 <div class="col-md-4"> 
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x }))
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your own HtmlHelper. I recommend tossing that away and using `MvcPaging`. [MvcPaging GitHub page](https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging)

You can find it via NuGet. It is a very complete package, which has a lot of options, among which: `MaxNrOfPages()`

It can be used the way you want like this:

```
@Html.Pager(pageSize, pageNumber, totalItemCount).Options(o => o.MaxNrOfPages(5))
// Show for example 5 pages.
```

Hope this helps, if so, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: In this case i am using HtmlHelper i want solution using this code

Comment: @user2589387 I accidentally saved my answer. See my updated answer, it uses an HtmlHelper too. I use this package in all my ASP.NET MVC project, it works great!

Comment: ok i will do but can you tell me any solution for this PagingHelpers
PageLinks